# ASP.NET Core Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I created a custom `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` attribute.

```
public class CustomeAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var dto = new DTO();
        var httpContextAccessor = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var requestBody = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Body;
        if (requestBody != null && requestBody.CanSeek)
        {
            requestBody.Position = 0;
            using var reader = new StreamReader(requestBody);
            var requestBodyString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            };
            dto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DTO>(requestBodyString, options);
        }
    }
}
```

in program.cs, I added the following

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter, CustomeAttribute>();
```

and

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    await next();
});
```

and I used the attribute in the controller as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomeAttribute )]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody] DTO dTO)
```

OnAuthorizationAsync Finish correctly, but then I receive the error:

{"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.String'."}

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The used [`StreamReader` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-io-streamreader-ctor(system-io-stream)) will result in the disposal of the passed stream:

> The `StreamReader` object calls `Dispose()` on the provided `Stream` object when `StreamReader.Dispose` is called.

Use constructor allowing to pass `leaveOpen` parameter:

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(requestBody, leaveOpen: true);
```

Notes:

1. Do not forget to rewind stream after reading it `requestBody.Position = 0;`
2. The faulty exception reporting `String` as disposed object should be fixed in the next ASP.NET Core version with [this PR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/54144).